# How can i identify if my web-application is making cache or not using webdriver/selenium

Tags: google-maps, selenium, caching, selenium-webdriver, browser-cache

Hi please help we are working on a web application which uses cardo db maps (like google maps) and what happens while performing some actions (like zoom in and zoom out) it creates a cache in the browser i am sure it does.but do not know how to identify the location of that cache so that i can perform some action on that  with selenium.please help.

More Update :

[image: a portion of the map]

below image shows a portion of the map a yellowish region in between the green bubbles.when we draw a circle on the map then that area becomes assigned to some region as as is the yellow region but what happens when we close the project and reopen the same location on the map the yellowish region is not shown in default mode but when we do some zoom in zoom out it appears

Comment: Take a step back and let us know what the problem is that you're having. Obviously if you have something definite about 'caches' please add that detail to your question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks for the support after having long discussion and research what we found that cache was building but not inside the browser but at the end of the cardoDB maps and that problem was form their side and now issue has been resolved and now its working fine.Sorry to every one if i was not clear any ways it got resolved